# Problem with displaying french character in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, character-encoding

I have to display "sélection?" in one of page that is viewed via iframe. But this is getting rendered as "s�lection?". If I view it requesting the page then it is rendering properly.
But if I view it in an iframe it gets changed. Same thing is happening in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just write `s&eacute;lection`.

What's happening is that your browser is displaying the page in another encoding (eg ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8). There are multiple reasons why this can happen:

1. The tag in your `<head>` says so.
2. The tag in the webservers response headers says so.
3. The browser is setup to override the formatting on the page.

If it works on the page itself, but when the page is in an iframe, **check the encoding of the page containing the iframe**. It will probably differ. Look for this kind of tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

And make sure they are the same on both pages (hint: you should probably be using UTF-8)

Comment: Hi, Hope someone can answer me. It seems this problem is long time ago but I have this problem now. Problem is i dont have access to the developer/coding site. I can only view the page now. Both in Chrome and IE displaying either square symbols or diamond symbols(as Niraj). I suspect is the encoding issues, so i try to set my browser encoding option but nothing happened. So may i know whether this problem can only be fixed at the back-end?

Comment: user: first of all, you are asking a question, but putting them in a new comment. Just create a new question. Second: it should be a question on superuser. Third: it is a backend problem, but you can try to change the 'page encoding' in your browser to tell your browser to interpret the page in another encoding - if the encoding is consistent, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the right charset?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`, I convert the document to UTF-8, you have all kind of software to convert it to you (dreamweaver, textedit, etc).